# Encrypt the traffic between Jboss and Oracle database server

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am trying to encrypt the traffic between application server and oracle database. My application uses a COTS solution and the cots solution asks to configure the jdbc URL. I cannot do any changes to the application side. Will oracle driver automatically encrypt and decrypt the traffic if I just provide some configuration in the JDBC URL. Please let me know.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/security/network_encrypt/ntwrkencrypt.htm

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_network_secure.htm#TDPSG60067